# How to get two bootstrap columns next to eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having problems with aligning my two col's next to eachother.
I feel like I'm doing right but I guess not.... Right now the second div (the col-11) appear underneath the col-1. The col-1 have an image inside it which I want to the far left and the other col right next to it.

```
<div class="container col-md-12 wm-body">

<div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">

    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">

        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
            <div class="row wm-card" style="margin: 15px 0 0 0; padding: 0px;">

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/trip.svg" class="icon">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <table *ngIf="trip" class="table-sm wm-table-drive-orders" style="width: 60%;">

                        <div>
                            <tbody class="col-md-12">
                                <tr *ngIf="firstNode">



                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <b>Datum</b>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <p>{{ tripHelper.getActualTimeStringFromNode(firstNode) }}</p>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(firstNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':
                                        tripHelper.getState(firstNode, true)}"></i>
                                    </td>



                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[0]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[0])}}
                                        </p>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                            <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                        </ng-container>-->
                                        <b>Tidskrav</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                        <b>Status</b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </div>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                            <tbody class="col-md-12">
                                <tr *ngIf="lastNode">

                                    <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                        <p>{{tripHelper.getDateString(trip)}}</p>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                        <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(lastNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':
                                            tripHelper.getState(lastNode, true)}"></i>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                        <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[1]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[1])}}
                                        </p>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                        <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                                <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                            </ng-container>-->
                                        <p>-</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                        <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                        <p>{{tripHelper.getStateString(trip)}}</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

I'm not sure if it's because I have tables inside the div? I honestly don't know.

Comment: You can't nest `container` elements.

Comment: div cannot be a direct child of the table element

Comment: So I just have to remove the container element inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having the issue is because you are nesting the container, row and col-* the wrong way. Bootstrap suggests to use container as parent for row not inside row or col. And also, you should not nest col-* inside another col-* unless you use a row to wrap the inner col-*. Try this code to make it more clearer.

```
<div class="container wm-body">

    <div class="wm-card" style="margin: 15px 0 0 0; padding: 0px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="../../../assets/img/trip.svg" class="icon">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-11">
                <table *ngIf="trip" class="table-sm wm-table-drive-orders" style="width: 60%;">

                    <div>
                        <tbody class="col-md-12">
                            <tr *ngIf="firstNode">



                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <b>Datum</b>
                                </td>

                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <p>{{ tripHelper.getActualTimeStringFromNode(firstNode) }}</p>
                                </td>

                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(firstNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':tripHelper.getState(firstNode, true)}"></i></td>



                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[0]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[0])}}
                                    </p>
                                </td>

                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                    <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                    </ng-container>-->
                                    <b>Tidskrav</b>
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                    <b>Status</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </div>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <tbody class="col-md-12">
                        <tr *ngIf="lastNode">

                            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                <p>{{tripHelper.getDateString(trip)}}</p>
                            </td>

                            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(lastNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':
                                                                                                                                                                                                            tripHelper.getState(lastNode, true)}"></i>
                            </td>

                            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[1]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[1])}}
                                </p>
                            </td>

                            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                </ng-container>-->
                                <p>-</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                                <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                <p>{{tripHelper.getStateString(trip)}}</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Happy coding...keep coding

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```css
.wm-table-drive-orders td {padding-bottom: 0px;}
.add-on-table td {padding-top: 0px;}

/* COMMON CLASSES */

.no-padding-left {padding-left: 0px;}
.no-padding-right {}
.no-side-padding {}
.no-padding {padding: 0;}

.no-margin {margin: 0;}

.width-40 {}
.width-50 {}
.width-60 {width: 60%;}

/* DEBUG */

.row {background: red;}
.col-md-1 {background: green;}
.col-md-11 {background: blue;}

table td {word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<div class="container wm-body">
    <div class="row no-margin">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            
            <div class="row wm-card no-padding" style="margin: 15px 0 0 0;">
                
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/trip.svg" class="icon">
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    
                    <table *ngIf="trip" class="table-sm wm-table-drive-orders width-60">
                        <tbody class="col-md-12">
                            <tr *ngIf="firstNode">
                                <td>
                                    <b>Datum</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{ tripHelper.getActualTimeStringFromNode(firstNode) }}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(firstNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':tripHelper.getState(firstNode, true)}"></i>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[0]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[0])}}
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                        <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                    </ng-container>-->
                                    <b>Tidskrav</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                    <b>Status</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                    <table class="add-on-table">
                        <tbody class="col-md-12">
                            <tr *ngIf="lastNode">
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{tripHelper.getDateString(trip)}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="tripHelper.getState(lastNode)" [ngStyle]="{'color':
                                        tripHelper.getState(lastNode, true)}"></i>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{ geographyHelper.getAddressString(trip.addresses[1]) }}, {{ geographyHelper.getPostalAreaString(trip.addresses[1])}}
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!--<ng-container *ngIf="trip.people">
                                            <p>{{peopleHelper.getPeopleNameString(trip.people)}} </p>
                                        </ng-container>-->
                                    <p>-</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- TODO: Add seat description -->
                                    <p>{{tripHelper.getStateString(trip)}}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/7925/